# How to create a real MediatR instance in test?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, mediatr

I want to write an integration tests, but I don't know how to make an Mediator instance. I saw examples using AutoFac, but I question how to do it myself.

Maybe this is not the way to go, but it's something I want anyway. Feel free to give feedback.

So I have a constructor in my controller like this:

```
FooController(IMediator mediator){
}
```

My test is like this:

```
FooControllerTest(){
  var mediator = ____ //this I don't get
  var controller = new FooController(mediator);

  //do testing stuff here
}
```

I've tried to create the mediator like this:

```
var mediator = new Mediator(new ServiceFactory());
```

But the ServiceFactory needs a System.Type object.
I tried to make a test instance of this type like this:

```
class TypeTestInstance : Type {}
```

And then the test:

```
FooControllerTest(){
  var mediator = new Mediator(new ServiceFactory(new TypeTestInstance()));
}
```

But in this example it gives an error method name expected, Stackoverflow says i need to do it like this: `new ServiceFactory(() => new TypeTestInstance());` but that doesn't work. It says Delegate ServiceFactory does not take 0 arguments. But then in this example I'm not even sure if it works or not.

So I'd like to hear how you solve this..

Comment: I prefer doing it like this: https://youtu.be/kPywu4GCGnk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are using an API using .NET Core but this answer may help
[Unit testing validation through MediatR PipelineBehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687927/unit-testing-validation-through-mediatr-pipelinebehavior/60696525#60696525).

Using testserver to hit the HTTP endpoint also tests any mediatr handlers that are being called and you can assert whatever things make your tests reasonable (has db stored a value, is response status x, does response contain x etc)